# I want to create a clickable button that loads a different iframe each time it is clicked from a list of video links

Tags: html

So I have no idea where to start, but I need to use iframes and on the click of a button load a different video source into that iframe from a list of video links.

Comment: You would create a function that the click of a button calls. This function, say `randomizeVideo()` will randomly pick an index from an array of video links and load into iframe.

Answer (score 1):

You need javascript to dynamically change the iframe url.

**JSFiddle:**

An example is worth a thousand words.

[jsfiddle.net/q1t6bz70/](https://jsfiddle.net/q1t6bz70/)

**Explanation:**

If this is your iframe element:

```
<iframe id="ifr"></iframe>
```

You can load urls in this frame with this defined function in javascript code:

```
<script>
   // all available urls
   var listOfUrls = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];
   // current url pointer
   var pointer = 0;

   function loadNewVideo() {
     // get iframe element by id
     var el = document.getElementById('ifr');
     // update pointer
     if(pointer + 1 >= listOfUrls.length) {
        pointer = 0;
     } else {
        pointer++;
     }
     // get new url
     var newUrl = listOfUrls[pointer];
     // assign new url to src property
     el.src = newUrl; 
   }
</script>
```

Now you can bind this function to a button element:

```
<button onclick="loadNewVideo()"></button>
```

Comment: When I click the button nothing happens, I see the src changing when I inspect the element on chrome but nothing gets loaded into the iframe.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle with an example and hope it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/q1t6bz70/

Comment: great answer bro